# Why is no padLeft function in my flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, padleft

My dart is `Dart SDK version: 2.10.4 (stable) (Wed Nov 11 13:35:58 2020 +0100) on "windows_x64"`, but I can't use `padLeft()`, does anyone tell me why? what can I do next?

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code where it is not working as it should work. May be yiu are using wrong data type.

Comment: can you tell me why?

Comment: `toString` is probably a method, so you'd want to call/invoke that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience in Dart but isn’t `toString` supposed to be a method? If so, you have to add parenthesis after its name like this: `id.toString()`.